# Is there a way to "check and set" the value of a `std::cell::Cell`?

Tags: rust, llvm, atomic

I was looking for something that would compile to the magical [`cmpxchg`](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#cmpxchg-instruction) instruction. After digging into
the documentation, I couldn't find anything that would accomplish this for [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html).

Maybe this is an antipattern?

### Code:

After digging into the code I added the following to `Cell`'s implementation to see if it would work.

```
pub fn cmp_and_set(&self, old: T, new: T) -> T {
    unsafe {
        ::intrinsics::atomic_cxchg(self.value.get(), old, new)
    }
}
// ^ there are many many reasons why this is not so great
// this is just an example of what I'm looking for
```

simple usage

```
fn main() {
    let c0 = Cell::new(10);
    let val0 = c0.cmp_and_set(11, 5);
    assert_eq!(c0.get(), 5);
    let val1 = c0.cmp_and_set(10, 42);
    assert_eq!(c0.get(), 42);
}
```

As far as I can tell, for very basic cases it works, but again there are many many reasons why the particular implementation is less than stellar.
The fact that I edited the standard library to get what I was looking for means I'm certainly attempting to implement some sort of antipattern.

### Background:

This was prompted from re-reading the following from [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/choosing-your-guarantees.html)

> It is still possible to violate your own invariants using this wrapper, so be careful when using it. If a field is wrapped in `Cell`, it's a nice indicator that the chunk of data is mutable and may not stay the same between the time you first read it and when you intend to use it.

Comment: My reading of that text is more along the lines of "`Cell` has interior mutability, so a method that accepts `&Cell` might change it. This is unlike other Rust code where a `mut` keyword makes it clear that it will change". I *don't* read it as "some thread somewhere might change the value at any time". Said another way, I don't think you need atomic checking or anything that complicated. Really, I read it as "`Cell` operates like any other object in a traditional OO language and that can be confusing with mutability, so watch out!".

Comment: Ah! You're right. For some reason I thought `Cell` impl'd Sync

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** No, there's not, because it's unnecessary.

---

Compare and Set is only valuable in two actors (or more) are modifying the object in parallel.

While `Cell` allows internal mutability, it is not thread-safe, so you will never be in a situation where two actors will be attempting to modify it in parallel.

Therefore, you can just use `get()`, compare, and `set()` if it suits you. And nobody will change the value between your `get()` and `set()`, providing you do not call other code yourself.